# PyScript - 'Pandas no columns to parse from file' on another page but works fine on index page

Tags: python, asp.net, pandas, pyscript

I am working in PyScript in ASP.Net in a .cshtml file to visualise data in tabular form.
I am able to display data from my CSV on a table form on my index.cshtml page but when i go to another page like for example 'charlie.cshtml' and paste the exact same code in I get a bunch of errors like:

`File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1235, in _make_engine return mapping[engine](f, **self.options) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 75, in __init__ self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds) File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 551, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse`

I checked my file path and its correct and I've tried some solutions mentioned on other pages like adding
`delim_whitespace=True` or adding '~/weather.csv' to my code but still throws errors. I even duplicated my index page, renamed it to 'test.cshtml' and even that threw me the same errors.

My PyScript code is:

```
<py-script output="jackie">
     import pandas as pd
     from pyodide.http import open_url
     link = open_url('weather.csv')
     df = pd.read_csv(link)
     df.head()
 </py-script>
```

^ **Note: I have declared the py-env and div for output in my files, above is what my 'py-script' section looks like**

Comment: I think the problem is here: `open_url('weather.csv')` Specify a complete URI.

Comment: I have tried the full file path but even that shows the same errors. What I am confused by is the fact that it works perfectly fine on my index page but when I copy the entire line to another page it throws these errors. It's the same thing when I copy the index page and rename it something else the error still appears

Comment: Open the browser debugger and check for additional errors in the Console and Network tabs.

Comment: The error "GET localhost:**PortNumber**/Home/weather.csv 404" error is appearing on the other page but not on the index page when I checked Console logs.

I just found out the solution to the issue after playing around with file paths etc., all I had to do was just add `open_url('/weather.csv')` and that seemed to fix this. Seemed like all I needed to add was the '/' and that found the weather.csv file

Comment: That is what I meant by complete URI. That can be `/weather.csv` if the host is the same or `https://www.example.com/weather.csv` if the host is different.